# How to resize a window programmatically with X11lib?

Tags: c++, c, resize, x11

I am creating an X11 window, which is then resized programmatically with `XWindowResize`:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    assert(display);

    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    assert(root);

    GLint att[] = { GLX_RGBA, GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 24, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, None };
    XVisualInfo* vi = glXChooseVisual(display, 0, att);
    assert(vi);

    XSetWindowAttributes swa;
    swa.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, root, vi->visual, AllocNone);
    swa.event_mask = ExposureMask | KeyPressMask;

    // create window with initial size 800 x 600
    Window window = XCreateWindow(display, root, 0, 0, 800, 600, 0, vi->depth, InputOutput, vi->visual, CWColormap | CWEventMask, &swa);
    XSelectInput(display, window, StructureNotifyMask | ResizeRedirectMask);
    XMapWindow(display, window);
    XFlush(display);

    // resize window to new size 400 x 300
    int result = XResizeWindow(display, window, 400, 300);
    printf("XResizeWindow  return value: %d\n", result);
    if (result == BadValue) printf("   bad value!!!\n");
    if (result == BadWindow) printf("   bad window!!!\n");

    XEvent event;
    XAnyEvent& ev = (XAnyEvent&)event;
    while (true)
    {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);

        if (ev.type == ResizeRequest)
        {
            XResizeRequestEvent& ev = (XResizeRequestEvent&)event;
            printf("request to resize to %d x %d\n", ev.width, ev.height);
        }

        XWindowAttributes xwa;
        XGetWindowAttributes(display, window, &xwa);
        printf("position: %d, %d     size: %d x %d\n", xwa.x, xwa.y, xwa.width, xwa.height);
    }
}
```

This is not working as expected. The window decoration drawn by the window manager indicates that it is indeed resized to 400x300 pixels, however, `XGetWindowAttributes` reports the contrary (output below). Changing position and size manually with the mouse has the same effect: the resize request reports the correct size, but it is not reflected in the output of `XGetWindowAttributes`. The problem is that this affects the area in which mouse events are detected as well as OpenGL drawing (removed in order to have a minimal example).

```
XResizeWindow  return value: 1
position: 1, 30     size: 800 x 600
position: 1, 30     size: 800 x 600
request to resize to 400 x 300
position: 1, 30     size: 800 x 600
position: 1, 30     size: 800 x 600
position: 1, 30     size: 800 x 600
```

Apparently I am doing it wrong. I'd appreciate any help on how to make this work. Do I have to do anything in order to honor the resize request? I have searched the web and stackoverflow for hours now without luck.

**EDIT:** It would already be helpful if someone could tell me whether the XResizeWindow return value of 1 indicates an error or not. I am unable to find documentation on the return value in case there is no error. Also, links to documentation containing this information are more than welcome!

Comment: A resize request does not mean that your window has been resized yet; just that resizing it has been requested. Whether and how that request is honored is decided by the window manager – the same goes for mapping the window, by the way. You request mapping from the window manager, but you are only mapped once you receive a MapNotify event. Do you really need to use lowlevel Xlib?

Comment: @Ingo: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, I really want low-level Xlib. I already checked the SFML code, and they also just call XWindowResize. Do you have any clue what goes wrong here? Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Just don't request `ResizeRedirectMask`! If you do, your windows size may be off. If you want to catch resizes, use `ConfigureNotify` events and `StructureNotifyMask`.

Comment: @n.m: Thanks for the hint - you nailed it, now it works! Could you turn the comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't request `ResizeRedirectMask`. It is supposed to be requested by one client at a time, which is normally your window manager. Except WMs usually request `SubstructureNotifyMaks` on the root, which takes precedence over `ResizeRedirectMask` on the children, so that the latter is quite useless. I couldn't find one single example of a program, WM or otherwise, that uses `ResizeRedirectMask`.

If you do request `ResizeRedirectMask`, your window attributes may be stuck with a wrong size.

If you need to catch actual size changes, request `StructureNotifyMask` and process `ConfigureNotify` events.